# WCF fails to import WSDL

Tags: wcf, serialization, wsdl

I'm trying to "Add Service Reference" with WCF to the following wsdl: https://se-face-webservice.redsara.es/sspp?wsdl

The visual studio does not provide any warning but the reference.cs is empty and no serialization took place.

I have already tried removing the "Reuse types in specified referenced assemblies", however the serialization stills fails.

If I tried to add the service with the WcfTestClient it gives an error stating that : 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/Array' is not defined.

Finally, when I add the wsdl through a "Add Web Reference" the serialization takes place. I'm guessing that maybe the service is using "unknown" bindings to WCF.

Is there a work around for this situation?

PS: If I use the SoapUI to generate the client everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your WSDL is faulty. It defines the prefix `soap-enc`, but does not define the schema which defines it. The WSDL is assuming that the `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/` schema is automatically defined.

Perhaps this service is built on an old version of Axis? I have seen that version assume that the consumer is also built on Axis.

Comment: The service belongs to the Spanish Tax Authority. I'm trying to build a client. Is there a workout around for WCF to work with old version of Axis? I really want to test that possibility.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried good old wsdl.exe for generating web service references with System.Web.Services and seems to work - generating and compilation at least :-)

Can you check it? Link to project on bitbucket. Just simple console app with references and generated assemblies.

https://bitbucket.org/polacekpavel/servicestack_27747564/src

and interesting one - generated proxy class https://bitbucket.org/polacekpavel/servicestack_27747564/src/c43b90221fae7ceb2e234552b9f57034551b3cbf/SSPPWebServiceProxyService.cs?at=master

Comment: Wsdl.exe is the same as doing a web service reference right? Wcf client services should be generated by svcutils.exe but that one does not work :(. Anyway thank you very much, I'm going to give a try.

Comment: Yeah "same" as svcutil.exe but with old System.Web.Service namespace but don't worry message to Axis will be same. Wsld.exe is used when you choose not "Add Service Reference" but when you use "Add Web Reference". You can choose it in advanced window at Add Service Reference. Yes little confusing - more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx